# Using the Read command to store multiple words in one variable

Tags: bash

I'm interested in storing an address in a variable called "address" using the `read` command in a Bash script.  However, I'm having an issue with the multiple words an address usually has.  Is there a way to store several words into one variable instead of just one? For example:

```
echo "Please enter your address"
[user puts in 123 Fake street]
read address
echo $address
[output is just 123]
```

Comment: I am getting `123 Fake street` ?

Comment: Seriously?  I just get the number 123.  If I use "-" like 123-Fake-Street, I'll get the entire line.  Its the white space its having trouble with

Comment: could you perform a `shopt` command and post the output into your question?

Comment: @Justin also check the `read` alias by `alias | grep 'read'` maybe it's aliased with `-d' '` option. I think

Comment: This isn't how bash behaves by default. Please post a complete script that reproduces the problem. (A complete bash script starts with `#!/bin/bash`)

Answer (score 4):

Normally `read address` should read the entire line of input into the variable.
The most probable cause of the different behavior in your case is that `IFS` has been changed from its default value.
If you change the line to this, it should work:

```
IFS= read -r address
```

And I suggest to review your entire script for places that alter `IFS`,
and if possible, avoid changing it.